# Probability of a year which is not a leap year

Tags: probability, calendar-computations

If a 4 digit year is choosen randomly, what is the probability that it is not a leap year ?

This problem has come in my exam and i have written like this

I know that the  number of four digit year is divisible by 4, so probability of a year which is not a leap year is 3/4. But When i have seen the answer key , answer is   probability of a year which is not a leap year is  $> 3/4$.

Please clear my doubt, Thank you

Comment: $2100$ is divisible by $4$.  It will not be a leap year.

Comment: I doubt that you would have been expected to know during an exam the exception, and the exception to the exception, for leap years (i.e., every 100 years it isn't, except every 400 years it is). It would be interesting to see the reasoning of the answer key. Let me also point out that you should be a bit more precise with your reasoning, since it just so happens that the number of 4-digit years is divisible by $4$. The probability that a random 4-digit year is divisible by, say, $7$ is not going to be exactly $1$ in $7$.

Answer (score 2):

There are 9000 four-digit years, running from 1000 AD to 9999 AD. Of these, there would be 2250 leap years, except for the century rule that excludes the years 2100, 2200, 2300, 2500, etc. There are 60 such excluded years from 2100 through 9900.

Furthermore **depending on which country you're in**, one or more of the years 1700 AD, 1800 AD and 1900 AD may also have been non-leap years, so the fraction of 4-digit years from 1000 AD to 9999 AD that *are* leap years is one of

$$ \frac{2187}{9000}=\frac{243}{1000} \qquad\quad \frac{2188}{9000}=\frac{547}{2550} \qquad\quad \frac{2189}{9000} \qquad\quad \frac{2190}{9000}=\frac{73}{300} $$

Answer (score 2):

You can look directly to the number of days in a year.

Depending on the used calendar / year, we get:

$$
\begin{array}{l|r|l}
\textrm{calendar / year} & days / year & P\\
\hline
\textrm{Gregorian calendar} & 365.2425\color{gray}{0} & 0.2425\\
\textrm{Julian calendar} & 365.25\color{gray}{000}& 0.25\\
\textrm{Hebrew calendar} & 365.2468\color{gray}{0} & 0.2468\\
\textrm{mean tropical year} & 365.24219 & 0.24219
\end{array}
$$

---

The number of days in a year is given by

$$
\Big\lfloor (n+k+1) \phi \Big\rfloor - \Big\lfloor (n + k ) \phi \Big\rfloor,
$$

where $k$ is an offset and $\phi$ is the number of days in a year, depending on the calandar or year.

The probability is then given by

$$
\Big\lfloor \phi \Big\rfloor.
$$

---

As for the question *not a leap year*, you need to reverse it, thus

$$
1 - \Big\lfloor \phi \Big\rfloor.
$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

From the very definition the number of leap years in every $400$ years in $$\left\lfloor\frac{400}4\right\rfloor -3$$

Comment: Some 4-digit years came before this definition was invented.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, Can you please share time of definition of share any reference ?

Comment: The [Gregorian calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) was promulgated by the pope in 1582 and adopted for civil timekeeping in different countries at various times between 1582 and 1923.